# Apache Usergrid, tomcat7 403 error on database setup

Tags: tomcat7, usergrid

I have setup usergrid following this [guide](http://usergrid.apache.org/docs/installation/deployment-guide.html).
Steps I have done include:
1. Setup Cassandra (`nodetool status`shows me one healty node and I can log in with `cqlsh`).
2. Setup ElasticSearch (`curl localhost:9200` gives me a nice .json back, everything ok.)
3. Built the usergrid app with `mvn clean install` and moved the built `ROOT.war`to `CATALINA_BASE`
4. Created `usergrid-deployment.properties`to `CATALINA_HOME` at `/usr/share/tomcat7`

When I start tomcat7 service everything goes ok, no errors in catalina logs. Last line is "Server Startup".

In `catalina.out` log I have the line:

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
>   Mar 08, 2016 9:33:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
>   
> INFO: **Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war**
>   Mar 08, 2016 10:02:50 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
>   INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [5$
>   Mar 08, 2016 10:02:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>   Mar 08, 2016 10:02:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   INFO: Server startup in 5561 ms

So the usergrid app should be running.

I can browse to `localhost:8080` and see the Tomcat7"It works" - page.

However, when I try to setup the usergrid database like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/system/database/setup -u [user]:[password]
```

I get a 403 error:

> Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

I am sure that my credentials match those that I have defined in `usergrid-deployment.properties` in `CATALINA_HOME` as usergrid `sysadmin.login` credentials.

In tomcat7 `localhost_access_log` I have the following output:

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [08/Mar/2016:12:27:43 +0200] "PUT /system/database/setup HTTP/1.1" 403 979

However (number2), when I try `curl -v localhost:8080/status` to see the status of the usergrid app, I get

> 404 - requested resource is not available

So, any help as to what I might do to:
a) be sure that the usergrid app is deployed correctly with tomcat (as there are no errors in logs
b) to solve the 403 issue?

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT:**

I noticed that my `CATALINA_BASE`(`/var/lib/tomcat/`) didn't have the `WEB_INF`directory inside `webapps` at all. In the guide I made reference to, we are only instructed to copy the  `ROOT.war` file to `webapps` directory. Is this correct? Should I also copy the WEB-INF files from the usergrid stack?

Here is what the guide says: 
*The next step is to deploy the Usergrid Stack software to Tomcat. There are a variey of ways of doing this and the simplest is probably to place the Usergrid Stack ROOT.war file into the Tomcat webapps directory, then restart Tomcat.*
I tried copying the `WEB-INF` files to `CATALINA_BASE` but that resulted in multiple errors and tomcat7 was unable to start:
This:

> 21:25:49,923  WARN Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl:31 - BadRequestException: [host=localhost(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=16(38), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)

And:

> INFO transport:93 - [node-1] bound_address {inet[0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9301]}
>   21:25:51,892  INFO discovery:85 - [node-1] elasticsearch/RIaKYgv1R-yTKJ_aknZOuw
>   21:25:51,905  WARN netty:620 - [node-1] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xc1bc7fca]], closing connection
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost:9200

**EDIT 2**: I was adviced that only Elasticsearch v 1.4.4 works (I tried with 2.2.0) and for Cassandra 1.2.x and 2.1.x versions (I tried with 3.0.3). I havent yet tried with these versions, I'll update this question if I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you but I do have a couple of observations:

- If you see the Tomcat "it works" page that means that you have not deployed the Usergrid ROOT.war file.
- If you see a 404 on /status, that also means Usergrid did not deploy properly.
- The Usergrid ROOT.war file that comes with the official release, includes the WEB-INF directory and you do not need to deploy that separately. The only files you need to add to Tomcat are ROOT.war, usergrid-deployment.properties and (optionally) log4j.properties.

The problem is probably that Usergrid is unable to connect to Cassandra or ElasticSearch and ROOT.war file fails to deploy to Tomcat.

If you share you Usergrid properties file (remove any passwords first), it might be easier to diagnose the problem that is preventing the Usergrid WAR file from being deployed.